# XML Parsing error after using the character "°" with UTF-8 encoding API

Tags: xml, utf-8, character-encoding

I have a issue with parsing in xml file.
There is a "°" in the sequence of characters and by that I get a notification: "XML Parsing error at line 1048: Input is not proper UTF-8, indicate encoding !". I had the same problem with the "&" character but I solved it by typing "&"
Here is a slice of the XML file:

```
<OrganisationListItem>
<Branch>
<Partner>
<PartnerShortName>xxxxx</PartnerShortName>
<BranchShortName>xxxxx</BranchShortName>
</Partner>
<BranchNumber>xxxxx</BranchNumber>
<BusinessName>xxxxx</BusinessName>
<StartDate>xxxxxx</StartDate>
<DisplayWeb>xxxxx</DisplayWeb>
<Address>
<Street>xxxxx 1° xxxxx</Street>
<ZipCode>xxxxxx</ZipCode>
<City>xxxxx</City>
<CountryCode>xxxxx</CountryCode>
</Address>
</Branch>
</OrganisationListItem>
```

Line 1048 is that line: "xxxxx 1° xxxxx". "Invalid UTF-8 start byte 0xb0 (at char #28494, byte #27999)"

Comment: (1) Please edit your post and share your XML. (2) What are you using to parse XML?

Comment: (1) done. (2) In this case, I edited the file manually

Comment: I checked your XML in Stylus Studio. Your XML is legit. Here is what was reported by Stylus Studio: "Checking Untitled1.xml...

The XML document Untitled1.xml is well-formed." Please specify where you are getting "XML Parsing error at line 1048: Input is not proper UTF-8, indicate encoding !"

Comment: Line 1048 is that line: "<Street>xxxxx 1° xxxxx</Street>".
"Invalid UTF-8 start byte 0xb0 (at char #28494, byte #27999)" that is what I got more.
I am sure it is a "°" sign, because if I remove it, I don't get it anymore.

Comment: Again, please specify where you are getting **"XML Parsing error at line 1048: Input is not proper UTF-8, indicate encoding !"**. What software (or API) you are using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The file starts with a declaration that declares the encoding to be UTF-8, so the parser is trying to decode it as UTF-8, and it decodes everything successfully until it finds the byte which you are displaying as "°", but which clearly is not the correct UTF-8 encoding of "°". To see what the actual encoding is, have a look at the content in a hex editor; the chances are, it's iso-8859-1 or something similar.

To fix the problem, examine the process by which the document was created, to discover why the encoding declared in the header doesn't match the actual way that the characters are encoded. It's possible that the error didn't arise when the document was first created, but happened later as a result of some transcoding, e.g. when sending the file from one machine to another.

If you're editing the file by hand, try to use a text editor that understands XML; that makes this problem much less likely to occur.